# Solving for $a$ (log probably required)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to get $c$ in terms of $a$.

Both $c, a\in \Bbb R^+$
$$
c^{2a} = c/a 
$$

I'm pretty sure that log is required to solve this, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

Comment: How about dividing by $c$ then taking the appropriate power?

Comment: @JonathanY. Oh, that seems like it might make more sense.  It just seemed to me like log would be needed, because of the powers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $c>0$, we may divide both sides by $c$ to obtain:
$$
c^{2a-1} = \frac1a
$$
To undo the exponent, we raise both sides of the equation to the power of $\dfrac{1}{2a-1}$ to obtain:
$$
c= \left(\frac1a\right)^{\dfrac{1}{2a-1}}
$$

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that this doesn't work if $a=\frac{1}{2}$; however, in that case the equation is $c=c/a$, so that either $a=1$ or $c=0$.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson If $a=\frac{1}{2}$, how can $a=1$?

Comment: Well, it can't.  So that tells you that $c=0$. :-P